# Create compressed archive with tar under Windows commandline - without parent directory

Tags: batch-file, cmd, compression, tar

I found some information about how to create a compressed tar archive without including the parent directory but the found solutions do not work in my case :-/
I have two drives on my Windows PC:
Drive `C:` and Drive `D:`
Now, i open the Commandline on **Drive `D:`** and try to execute following command:

```
tar -C C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop -cvzf MyArchive.tar.gz MyArchive
```

Normally, the `-C`should change the directory to the given one - so that the directory "MyArchive" will be archived and compressed without it´s parent folders.
But in my case, the the archive will be created under the drive `D:` ...
Does anyone know, why tar doesn´t create the archive on Drive `C:` as given with the parameter `-C ...`, but on drive `D:` ?

Greets

Comment: The archive file name `MyArchive.tar.gz` is specified without any path which means in the current directory __on starting__ `tar.exe`. The option `-C` is for specifying the current directory just for adding files and folders to an archive and for extraction of files and folders from an archive. An archive file referenced with a relative path is always created respectively searched on extraction using the __current directory on starting__ the `tar.exe`. Read also chapter __6.10.1 Changing the Working Directory__ of the [GNU TAR manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/).

Comment: In other words the option `-C <dir>` can be used one or more times in the command options list of `tar` but it affects only from which directory files and directories specified next are added to an archive file or to which directory are extracted files from an archive file with an archive file name with a relative path being always interpreted relative to current directory on starting `tar` independent on where and how often `-C <dir>` is used in the command options list.

Comment: The command line to use in the batch file for this use case is: `%SystemRoot%\System32\tar.exe -czf "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\MyArchive.tar.gz" -C "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop" MyArchive`

Comment: @Mofi: What shall i say? - That just works ;-D. Thank´s a lot for the advice and the link to the GNU TAR manual.